# Backbone Views and webshims for form values

Tags: backbone.js, webshim

What is the best way to make use of webshims in a backbone project?  Is there  a way to avoid using it globally and only loading it for a specific view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible. But I would always include the modernizr and polyfiller.js in the base setup.

In case you are doing this you should configure at least waitReady and basePath:

```
webshims.setOptions({ waitReady: false, basePath: "/js/libs/shims/" });
```

Your code for your view could look like this:

```
Backbone.View.extend({

  initialize: function(){
    //Load webshims
    webshims.polyfill('forms forms-ext mediaelement');
  },

  render: function() {
    this.$el.html( this.template(this.model.attributes) );
    //update new created elements
    this.$el.updatePolyfill();
    return this;
  }

});
```

Normally webshims delays jQuery's 'ready' event until all features are implented. In case you want to use webshims only in a specific view you can't delay it. In case you want to use the polyfilled JS/DOM API. You should wrap your JS code, which uses those APIs in a webshims.ready callback:

```
render: function() {
    var thisObject = this;
    this.$el.html( this.template(this.model.attributes) );
    //update new created elements
    this.$el.updatePolyfill();

    //wait until video API is implemented and then use it
    webshims.ready('mediaelement', function(){
        $('video', thisObject.$el).play();
    });
    return this;
}
```

In case you want to speed up things, you can load it inside your view and after window.load:

```
   $(window).on('load', function(){
      //preload after onload
      webshims.polyfill('forms forms-ext mediaelement');
   });
```

This way webshims is loaded either as soon as the view starts to initialize or after onload. webshims might give you a warning in this case, that you have called it twice, but this won't hurt.

Comment: This is great, thank you. I was running in to problems when rendering on update.   Is there anything special that needs to be done when switching between views?  Will this cause any memory leaks?

Comment: Webshims hooks into $.cleanData (https://github.com/aFarkas/webshim/blob/1b4d8dcabdd84b7b8f98a4a3ec6454057aba61b1/src/shims/dom-extend.js#L90-105). So webshims is automatically destroying the widget as long as you are using jQuery methods to remove ($.remove, $.empty) or to manipulate ($.html).

Comment: Thanks again. Using webshims seems to automatically create detached dom elements some how.  Some elements are still attached to the view after the view has been removed.

Comment: Can you give me a testcase?

Comment: @user2961953 I really need more information on this. Best would if you could write a testcase/example. Which elements are still there? Where are those elements being appended in the DOM?

Comment: Thanks again for your help.  I will set up a test case and post it tomorrow.

Comment: @user2961953 As long as you can not provide a testcase. What elements are still in the view? Where do they be in the DOM?

Comment: this.$el.updatePolyfill(); <--- thanks so much, this did it for me!